# PyQt5 QWebEngineView not Displaying Anything

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

So I'm building a simple Web Browser using PyQt5, with QtWebEngineView, it works fine, but when I type something in the address bar and hit enter, the current page changes but the entered web address does not load, the screen remains blank.

It doesn't work with `https://` either

```python
"""A Simple Web Browser Written in Python and PyQt5"""

import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QToolBar, QAction, QLineEdit


class PyChromeWindow(QMainWindow):
    DEFAULT_SEARCH_ENGINE = QUrl("https://www.google.com")

    def __init__(self):
        super(PyChromeWindow, self).__init__()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.browser.setUrl(self.DEFAULT_SEARCH_ENGINE)

        # ToolBar
        self.browser_tool_bar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(self.browser_tool_bar)

        # Back Action
        self.back_btn = QAction(QIcon('./resources/back_arrow16px.png'), 'Back')
        self.back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        self.browser_tool_bar.addAction(self.back_btn)

        # Forward Action
        self.forward_action = QAction(QIcon('./resources/forward_arrow16px.png'), 'Forward')
        self.forward_action.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        self.browser_tool_bar.addAction(self.forward_action)

        # Refresh Action
        self.refresh_action = QAction(QIcon('./resources/refresh_icon16px.png'), 'Refresh')
        self.refresh_action.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        self.browser_tool_bar.addAction(self.refresh_action)

        # Home Action
        self.home_action = QAction(QIcon('./resources/home_icon16px.png'), 'Home')
        self.home_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.browser.setUrl(self.DEFAULT_SEARCH_ENGINE))
        self.browser_tool_bar.addAction(self.home_action)

        # Address Bar
        self.address_bar = QLineEdit()
        self.address_bar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        self.browser_tool_bar.addWidget(self.address_bar)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.showMaximized()

    def navigate_to_url(self):
        """Navigate to a specific URL"""
        url = QUrl(self.address_bar.text())
        self.browser.load(url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("PyChrome")
    window = PyChromeWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: Screen Remains Blank]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"www.google.com" is not a valid url for QWebEngineView, in this case you must use [`QUrl::fromUserInput()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromUserInput) which deduces a valid url.

```py
url = QUrl.fromUserInput(self.address_bar.text())
```